# Прием подключений из WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, сокет, tcplistener

Задача: принять подключение извне, спросить через MessegeBox принять ли подключение и, в случее утвердительного ответа, открыть другое окно.

Проблема в том, что если ожидать подключение в основном потоке, в конструкторе или в Window_Load, то окно зависает. А если ожидать подключение в отдельном потоке, то не получается открыть другое окно из-за того, что окно должно быть открыто в основном потоке. Что делать?

Comment: Dispatcher.Invoke

Comment: @АндрейNOP , не вариант - в этом случее главное окно даже не отображается

Comment: Значит вы наверно что то делаете не так? Показывайте свои попытки и будем разбираться. Без этих данных нам остается лишь "ванговать".